# join two collections by a common field and get only a few fields

Tags: mongodb, join, collections

I'm new to MongoDB and I have 2 collections, one called "EN" and another one called "csv_import". I just need to join these 2 collections using a common field and get the results. For results, I just need the Part number and product id. The 2 collections structure is as follow:

csv_import:

```
product_id
part_no
vendor_standard
```

EN:
under object "ICECAT-interface.Product":

```
@Prod_id
@Name
```

(these are the main ones but there are other non important fields, for the sake of this example I'm including only relevant ones.

just as clarification, "@" is part of the field name

I'm using this to join the two collections:

```
db.EN.aggregate([
 {
     $lookup: {
  from: 'csv_import',
  localField: 'ICECAT-interface.Product.@Prod_id',
  foreignField: 'part_no',
  as: 'part_number'
     }
 }]);
```

Unfortunately, I get an empty array (see screenshot) when I'm expecting just the results that match. Also, how can I specify which fields I want to get back? I thought adding "as: part_number" would be enough but doesn't seem to be the case

[image: Results capture]

Here's some collection sample (taken from "EN")

```
[{
  "_id": "1414",
  "ICECAT-interface": {
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation": "https://data.icecat.biz/xsd/ICECAT-interface_response.xsd",
    "Product": {
      "@Code": "1",
      "@HighPic": "https://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/1414-HP.jpg",
      "@HighPicHeight": "400",
      "@HighPicSize": "43288",
      "@HighPicWidth": "400",
      "@ID": "1414",
      "@LowPic": "https://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/low/1414-HP.jpg",
      "@LowPicHeight": "200",
      "@LowPicSize": "17390",
      "@LowPicWidth": "200",
      "@Name": "C6614NE",
      "@IntName": "C6614NE",
      "@LocalName": "",
      "@Pic500x500": "https://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery_mediums/img_1414_medium_1480667779_072_2323.jpg",
      "@Pic500x500Height": "500",
      "@Pic500x500Size": "101045",
      "@Pic500x500Width": "500",
      "@Prod_id": "C6614NE",
```

Sample collection data taken from "csv_import" collection:

```
{
  "_id": "ObjectId(\"6348339cc6e5c8ce0b7da5a4\")",
  "index": 23679,
  "product_id": 4019734,
  "part_no": "CP-HAR-EP-ADVANCED-REN-1Y",
  "vendor_standard": "Check Point"
},
```

**EDIT**
I was able to run this:

```
db.EN.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "csv_import",
      let: { pn: "$ICECAT-interface.Product.@Prod_id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$pn", "$part_no" ] } } }
      ],
      as: "part_number_info"
    }
  },
  { $match: { part_number_info: { $ne: [] } } }
])
```

But it takes ages to complete a (lot of CPU processing) and I ran explain and it does a COLLSCAN, I do have an index on @Prod_id, not sure if I need an additional index

Comment: Can you add sample documents (not as image, but json) for the related collections and the expected output?

Comment: added sample collection data. I just need 2 fields: either part_no (from csv_import) or @Prod_id (from EN) and the product id which is on csv_import

Comment: Which fields are supposed to match for join? In your sample documents, no localField matches the foreignField.

Comment: Local fields are supposed to be fields under "EN" collection and foreign fields under csv_import right?

Comment: In this case, @Prod_id being local needs to match part_no foreign

Comment: Am I missing something here? I was reading about pipeline, is that what I need to use to get a match and not a "left join"?

Comment: I just edited the question and added something I was able to run to match the ones that actually exists